# Jaas/Kerberos : specify LoginModule elsewhere than in the configuration file

Tags: java, configuration, kerberos, jaas

I'm using jaas to authenticate threw a Kerberos server. I use the Krb5LoginModule to get the ticket in the cache. It works but I always have to specify the configuration file below to run the java app, like this :

```
java com.company.maclasse -Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas.conf
```

jaas.conf :

```
com.orange.rolefilter.LDAPManager {
        com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule
        required
        client=TRUE
        doNotPrompt=TRUE
        useTicketCache=TRUE
        storeKey=FALSE
        useKeyTab=FALSE;
};
```

I would like to know if there is a way to specify this Krb5LoginModule elsewhere than in a configuration file, I want it to be taken into account at the compilation for example. In a way to not having to specify it after.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seems like there's a way, either ship the config file, or have the code write out the config file when its being run.